# How can i replace tab spaces by ',' in a file using python?

Tags: python

I have a file with level, equation and answer (separated by tabs), for a math game. For example:

```
Lvl     Eq      Ans
2       2*6     12
```

How can I replace the tab space by a comma `,` in a new file?

Comment: If you want to, what's stopping you? Ask a specific question

Comment: @AndrewL. Sorry for my idiotic way of asking

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read the lines from the old file and replace `'\t'` with `','` in the new file. This should do:

```
with open('oldfile.txt') as fin, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace('\t', ','))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.replace#str.replace) method like this:

```
>>> s = '2\t2*6\t12'
>>> print s
2       2*6     12
>>> s.replace('\t', ',')
2,2*6,12
```